# Respuesta automatica formulario php

Tags: php, formularios

tengo un formulario basico y necesito saber como configurar una respuesta automatica que adjunte el archivo correspondiente a "opcion 1" u "opcion 2". Puede alguien ayudarme. Gracias

```
                <form action="envio.php" name="envio.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-inline">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                    <select name="opciones" class="form-control">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Enviar">
                </form>
```

Este es el formulario modificado

Comment: ¿Que has intentado en tu `envio.php`? segun tengo entendido, segun el opcion que seleccionas, debe retornar una respuesta o otra? En tu `option` debes añadir `value` ,es decir. <option value="respuesta1">texto a mostrar</option>`.

Comment: Gracias por responder. Añadi esto al envio.php:  $selectOption = $_POST['opciones'];

Comment: Esta correcto para obtener el valor de tu `option`, ahora si quieres comprobar si es `1` o `2` podrías hacer algo así: `if($selectOption==1){ //Respuesta 1  } else { //respuesta 2. }`, como no está claro, si quieres imprimir la respuesta en pantalla o enviarlo por correo, deberías aclarar un poco más que es lo que quieres hacer exactamente, así obtendrás una mejor respuesta a tus necesidades. Mejor si añades también `envio.php`.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo haría con la clase `PHPMailer`, que la puedes descargar desde aquí [PHPMailer Github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

El codígo que debería usar sería algo similar a este

```
<?php

    require_once("includes/constantes.php");

            error_reporting(E_STRICT);
            date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
            require_once('includes/class.phpmailer.php');
            //include("class.smtp.php");                                    // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not 
                                                                            // already loaded
            $mail             = new PHPMailer();
            $mail->IsSMTP();                                                // telling the class to use SMTP
            $mail->Host       = $SERVIDOR_SMTP;                             // SMTP server
            $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                                          // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                                                            // 1 = errors and messages
                                                                            // 2 = messages only
            $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                       // enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->Host       = $SERVIDOR_SMTP;                             // sets the SMTP server
            $mail->Port       = 25;                                         // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
            $mail->Username   = $correo_Usuario;                            // SMTP account username
            $mail->Password   = $correo_Clave;                              // SMTP account password
            $mail->SetFrom( $correo_copia, $correo_NombreCliente);
            $mail->AddReplyTo($correo, $correo_NombreCliente);
            $mail->AddCC($correo_copia,"");
            $mail->AddCC($correo1,"");
            if ($achivo !="none") {
                 $mail->AddAttachment($archivo,$archivo_name);
            }

            if (isset($dirtemp)){
                 $mail->AddAttachment($dirtemp,"Parte del Siniestro");
            }
            //$mail->AddBCC($correo_administrativo, $correo_NombreAdministrativo);
            $mail->Subject    = strtoupper($asunto);
            $mail->MsgHTML($body);
            $address = $correo_destino_usado;

            //echo "direccion:".$address;

            $mail->AddAddress($address);


?>
```

Donde debes definir tus variables del servidor, correos, contraseñas y demás variables.

La parte que te importa sería el código

```
if ($achivo !="none") {
    $mail->AddAttachment($archivo,$archivo_name);
      }
```

Donde `$archivo` será la ruta del adjunto y `$archivo_name`sería el nombre del fichero que aparecerá en el correo